# How can I view & access all available variables for a Drupal Commerce cart?

Tags: commerce

For theming purposes I'm trying to access any and all available Drupal commerce cart variables. For starters, I want to give the user feedback regarding the cart in the global nav.

I thought these vars would be available within the $_SESSION var but not so(?).

an example of what i’m trying to do is as follows, via some pseudo code to be put into the global nav…

```
<!—- Global nav—->
<li>Cart 
    <?php  if($items_in_cart == true) {
        echo ‘*’;
     } ?></li>
```

or,....

```
<?php
if($items_in_cart) {
print $total_items_in_cart;
}?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [`commerce_cart_order_load`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21commerce%21modules%21cart%21commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_order_load/7) & [`commerce_line_item_load()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!line_item!commerce_line_item.module/function/commerce_line_item_load/7) to load the current order(cart) object & order product objects respectively:

```
  global $user;
  $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
  $cart_items = array();
  foreach ($order->commerce_line_items[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $line_item) {
    $cart_items[] = commerce_line_item_load($line_item['line_item_id']);
  }
```

In this example, `$order` contains the Commerce order(cart) object for the current user & `$cart_items` contain an array of line item (order products) objects.

Comment: great, thank you. can you recommend, where would i put such code. so that vars are available for theming purposes? would you put in template->html.tpl.php or page.tpl.php ?

Comment: guess i'm wrong in thinking that if i add to html.tpl.php the vars would be available later in block--myNav.tpl.php.

Comment: That's another question but, you can place a `MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables)`,  `MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables)`, or `MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables)` function (depending on your needed scope) in your theme's **template.php** file with MYTHEME replaced with your theme's short name. Any array element you add to `$variables` in these functions will be available to *page.tpl.php*, *html.tpl.php* or *block.tpl.php* (e.g. adding `$variables['example'] = "test';` to the page preprocess function will make it available as `$example` inside *page.tpl.php*).